# "Initialiser requires a body."

Tags: swift

When I call the intitializer following the statement it gives me an error "Initializer requires a body"

```
init(identifier: String,
     bootFromRecovery: Bool = false,
        {
    self.bootFromRecovery = bootFromRecovery
}
```

Any ideas/fixes?

Also it gives me another error "Expected parameter name followed by ':'"

Anything helps!

I tried rewrite and it wasn't working

Comment: This code has an extra comma and is missing a parenthesis

Comment: You are DEFINING an initializer, not calling one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just forgot a closing `)`:

```swift
init(identifier: String, bootFromRecovery: Bool = false) {
    self.bootFromRecovery = bootFromRecovery
}
```

Comment: ... and he has an extra comma, as pointed out by lorem ipsum. (voted)